# How remove shared links created from a specific user after leaving the company?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm looking for a solution, but haven't found anything yet. I almost can't believe that this isn't a problem for many people:

1 - person has created many sharelinks in OneDrive and ShrePoint
2 - person leaves company
3 - Sharelinks from this person are still active

Nobody knows what data this person has shared with whom. Even after leaving.

This is a serious DLP issue

How can the share links be removed from SharePoint and OneDrive?
On the one hand, I can pull an audit report from this user and see which items have been shared. But how exactly do I remove these specific shares? Only the shares created by this specific user, not all shares of an item/site/library/list which can also be shared by other users and must remain active.